# How to add multiple emails to a sendgrid mailinglist using guzzle

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid, guzzle

I think I just have a problem with my syntax. I can add one user at a time no problem just fine:

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $data = [
        'api_user' => $this->api_user,
        'api_key' => $this->api_key,
        'list' => 'listname',
        'data' => json_encode(array('email' => 'example@email.com', 'name' => 'example'))
    ];

    $client->post('https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json', ['body' => $data]);
```

Now I can't figure out how to specify multiple emails using guzzle. Sendgrid's docs (https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/emails.html) show a curl example using multiple `data[]={..json..}` params, which I can't figure out how to specify with Guzzle.

So far I've tried a multidimensional array, which doesn't work because I believe I need to pass them as separate params, not as one:

```
    $data = [
        'api_user' => $this->api_user,
        'api_key' => $this->api_key,
        'list' => 'listname',
        'data' => json_encode(array(
            array('email' => 'example1@email.com', 'name' => 'example1'),
            array('email' => 'example2@email.com', 'name' => 'example2'),
            array('email' => 'example3@email.com', 'name' => 'example3')
        ))
    ];
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @StevenMusumeche unfortunately no, and I think it's just a stupid syntax problem

Comment: I managed to get it working by creating a command line curl string. Lame.